# How to disable child object from a List of GameObjects Unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a list of Gameobject where I am trying to enable and disable child objects based on a case. The problem is when I try to use `SetActive` or `active` I am getting a `UnityEngine.Transform does not contain a definition for active and SetActive errors`

```
public List<Transform> components;

for(int i = 0; i <= components.Count ; i++)
{   
    if(index == i)
    {
        components[i].Find("amount").SetActive(false);
        components[i].Find("confirm").active = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SetActive](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) is used for the gameobject, not the transform.
Simply access the gameobject of the transform instead:

```
components[i].Find("amount").gameobject.SetActive(false);
```